# Eclipse icon and start screen does not change after ADT installed

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am a starter of Android developing, and I have installed ADT from adt bundle(down load at: https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip), after unziped, the eclipse icon in eclipse doesn't change to ADT icon, and the start screen is also general eclipse's.
[image]

How can  change the icon and start screen to ADT(also it doesn't affect the normal use).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason not to, please use Android Studio instead. It is the modern IDE to use for android development. Support for eclipse ADT has been deprecated. You can get Android Studio at http://d.android.com.

Comment: You are quite right, but the question is how to change the icon of eclipse ADT

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I understand. There should be no need to use eclipse or ADT at all. Is there a specific reason you are trying to use eclipse? Take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html